# Page Layout Migration to Professional Edition via AppExchange product

Tags: professional-edition

I have an App avaiable in AppExchange which contains "page layout" for contact and account also as one its component.

When I install this app in Other Edition the page layout is  getting migrated but If I install the same App in Professional Edition then the Page layout is not getting migrated.

As per my understanding there is only one by-default page layout for each object in professional Edition and user can not create a new page layout from the UI.

Please let me know how to migrate the page Layout to professional Edition org via installing an App from AppExchange

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not without Professional Edition Record Types (upgrade option for Professional Edition).

It's not a feature you can add to your app, it's a feature the client would have to pay for. You can't even metadata changes into the org without them getting the API, because metadata API doesn't support client Id values.

Comment: thanks for the reply, can I update the existing pageLayout using metadata API and PostInstall Script.